# FOR loop with the table name as a variable

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to create a FOR loop to loop through an array list of table names.

Something like

```
list=['tableA','tableB','tableC'];
for x in list{
  select * from x;
}
```

basically doing this

```
select * from tableA;
select * from tableB;
select * from tableC;
```

This is what I've gotten so far.

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    dataTable TEXT;
    countData integer;
BEGIN
FOREACH dataTable IN ARRAY ARRAY['tableA','tableB','tableC'] 
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'hello %', dataTable;
--      EXECUTE 'select count(*) from' || quote_ident(dataTable);
        select count(*) into countData from quote_ident(dataTable);
        RAISE NOTICE 'count %', countData;
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

Which results in

```
NOTICE:  hello tableA
NOTICE:  count 1
NOTICE:  hello tableB
NOTICE:  count 1
NOTICE:  hello tableC
NOTICE:  count 1
DO
```

(not sure where the DO is coming from and why the value of `dataCount` is 1. All the tables listed has data; more than 1 row. )

Im using SELECT as a test, but my endgoal is basically trying to execute SQL statements in a FOR loop with the table names being variables.(so, instead of SELECT, I want to use...say INSERT or DELETE)

I saw a few solutions that uses the table INFORMATION_SHCEMA or something but this is not what Im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Uncomment this line**

> `EXECUTE 'select count(*) from' || quote_ident(dataTable);`

**Add space between from and single quote and change the query to**

> `EXECUTE 'select count(*) from '  ||dataTable INTO countData;`

**Comment the line below**

> `--select count(*) into countData from quote_ident(dataTable);`

The reason you get 1 every time because in your query, if you pass any string variable in quote_indent() it will return 1 try this `execute 'SELECT count(*) FROM '||quote_ident('xyz');` and the result will be the same, this means instead of treating the value in a variable as a table name it is treating it as a plain string only.

Comment: Running ```SELECT count(*) FROM quote_ident('xyz');``` by itself gave me the results as you said, but running it as part of my loop, as the other answer stated (```EXECUTE 'select count(*) from ' || quote_ident(dataTable) into countData;``` ), actually gave me similar answers to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    dataTable TEXT;
    countData integer;
BEGIN
FOREACH dataTable IN ARRAY ARRAY['int2_tbl','int4_tbl','int8_tbl'] 
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'hello %', dataTable;
        EXECUTE 'select count(*) from ' || quote_ident(dataTable) into countData;
      
        RAISE NOTICE 'count %', countData;
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

**from** here need extra space, otherwise string will be concatenate together.